# az servicebus list gives NoneType error in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, command-line-interface

**Command Name**
I tried `az servicebus namespace list` but after some outputs it gives me NoneType error means no data is retrieved. The installed python packages are provided in this link https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/18428#issuecomment-858293708

**Errors:**

```
The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:
'NoneType' object is not iterable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\knack\cli.py", line 231, in invoke
    cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 657, in execute
    raise ex
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 720, in _run_jobs_serially
    results.append(self._run_job(expanded_arg, cmd_copy))
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 704, in _run_job
    result = list(result)
  File "C:\Users\Mp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\azure\core\paging.py", line 129, in __next__
    return next(self._page_iterator)
  File "C:\Users\Mp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\azure\core\paging.py", line 84, in __next__
    self.continuation_token, self._current_page = self._extract_data(self._response)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\azure\mgmt\servicebus\operations\_namespaces_operations.py", line 371, in extract_data
    return deserialized.next_link or None, iter(list_of_elem)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

### To Reproduce:

- `az servicebus namespace list --subscription {} --query {} --output {}`

### Expected Behavior

To give list of azure servicebus in a specific subscription

### Environment Summary

```
Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
Python 3.8.9
Installer: MSI

azure-cli 2.24.0 *

Extensions:
logic 0.1.3
```

Update

I have realized that this error exist only when there are no servicebus in the account. Instead of giving value = [] cli raise this error.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me, probably you are not passing some values, check the command below,

```
az servicebus namespace authorization-rule list --resource-group myresourcegroup --namespace-name mynamespace
```

Comment: I am trying to list all the servicebus associated with a subscription therefore i cannot pass --namespace-name parameter